# Does order of records in table matter?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a simple stock market portfolio manager and have a question which, I believe, relates to the order of the records in my database table.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'transactions' (
  'positionID' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'date' date DEFAULT NULL,
  'mode' varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  'company' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'units' int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  'price' float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Just to summarize, my table of transactions contains a record for my initial purchase, and subsequent dividend reinvestments.

Here's my data:

```
15,2018-02-28,Reinvestment,Ford,877,13.25
15,2017-11-30,Reinvestment,Ford,26,10.47
15,2016-09-13,Purchase,Ford,20,13.07
15,2019-08-30,Reinvestment,Ford,25,12.64

44,2015-12-05,Purchase,Oracle,87,52.18
44,2017-07-13,Reinvestment,Oracle,449,60.64
44,2018-03-29,Reinvestment,Oracle,84,54.01
44,2019-05-07,Reinvestment,Oracle,59,67.24

21,2016-10-13,Purchase,Ford,10,6.54
21,2018-03-30,Reinvestment,Ford,439,6.63
21,2017-12-30,Reinvestment,Ford,13,5.24
21,2019-09-29,Reinvestment,Ford,13,6.32
```

I would like to list all my positions grouped by positionid and accumulated units.  With each positionid, I would like to list initial purchase date (mode = 'Purchase') and duration of holding since initial purchase.  This is what I wrote:

```
SELECT
  t.positionid,
  t.company,
  IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', t.date, '') AS purchaseDate,
  IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t.date), '') AS duration,
  ROUND(SUM(t.units), 3) AS currentHolding,
  IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', ROUND(t.price, 3), '') AS cost
FROM transactions t
GROUP BY t.positionid
ORDER BY t.company, t.date
```

Here's the result I got:

```
21,Ford,2016-10-13,1117,475.000,6.540
15,Ford,,,948.000,
44,Oracle,2015-12-05,1430,679.000,52.180
```

My problem is ... for position 15, I don't see the purchaseDate and duration.  I believe this is because the records for position=15 are not in chronological order.  If the 'Purchase' record were the first, I could have gotten what I wanted.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `GROUP BY` without aggregating the columns in the `SELECT` list and you don't use in the `GROUP BY` clause the column `t.company` which you select.
This may be allowed by MySql but sometimes leads to unexpected results.
Change to this:

```
SELECT
  t.positionid,
  t.company,
  MAX(IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', t.date, '')) AS purchaseDate,
  MAX(IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), t.date), '')) AS duration,
  ROUND(SUM(t.units), 3) AS currentHolding,
  MAX(IF(t.mode = 'Purchase', ROUND(t.price, 3), '')) AS cost
FROM transactions t
GROUP BY t.positionid, t.company
ORDER BY t.company, purchaseDate
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXtJRW5hmS6frcwMY63nM1/1).
Results:

```
| positionid | company | purchaseDate        | duration | currentHolding | cost   |
| ---------- | ------- | ------------------- | -------- | -------------- | ------ |
| 15         | Ford    | 2016-09-13 00:00:00 | 1147     | 948            | 13.070 |
| 21         | Ford    | 2016-10-13 00:00:00 | 1117     | 475            | 6.540  |
| 44         | Oracle  | 2015-12-05 00:00:00 | 1430     | 679            | 52.180 |
```

Comment: Vote up. Great and fast :) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd3080939680032403be4b4f2df0bac6

Comment: Thanks for fast response.  Works!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using a simple join

```
SELECT
  t.positionid,
  t.company,
  pt.date AS purchaseDate,
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), pt.date) AS duration,
  ROUND(SUM(t.units), 3) AS currentHolding,
  ROUND(pt.price, 3) AS cost
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN transactions pt ON t.positionid = pt.positionid
WHERE pt.mode = 'Purchase'
GROUP BY t.positionid
ORDER BY t.company, t.date
```